# Set of convergent sequences that converge to 3 is measurable

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Show that the set of all sequences converging to 3 is measurable wrt $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}})=\displaystyle\bigotimes_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

My idea:

Let $M=\{(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\,|\,\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$, s.t. $|x_{n}-3|<3\,\forall n>N\}$. Let $\pi_{i}:\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the projction onto the ith coordinate. Then, with $(3-\frac{1}{m},3+\frac{1}{m})\in\mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}})$, it follows for the preimage $\pi_{i}^{-1}((3-\frac{1}{m},3+\frac{1}{m}))\in\displaystyle\bigotimes_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}})$ by definition of $\displaystyle\bigotimes_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}})$. So we have that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i>N}\pi_{i}^{-1}((3-\frac{1}{m},3+\frac{1}{m}))\,\cup\,\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}\pi_{i}^{-1}(\{x_{i}\})\in\displaystyle\bigotimes_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}})$, because singletons belong to $\displaystyle\mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}})$ and the stability under countable unions of $\displaystyle\bigotimes_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}})$.

Now, in order to get the measurability of the whole set $M$, I somehow need to include $m$ and all possible $N$ (which can be at least countably many, since $N\in\mathbb{N}$).

Can someone give me a hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The set of all sequences converging to $3$ is closed and so it is a Borel set.